# Draw floating div over editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So i like to do extensions for the editors I use, and I am finding difficult to understand how can i draw a floating div over the editor as I am unable to get hold of any of underlaying documents to append a child div.

My intention is to achieve something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that allows something similar is the socalled previewHTML feature (you can find an [example for that on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/previewhtml-sample)). The idea is to register a text document provider which generates the HTML to show in the preview. In the last month's vscode update the introduced a parameter `preview` for normal text document, which is supposed to simplify handling, but I haven't tried this out yet.

I use this preview feature for [railroad diagrams](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4) and network graph display.

Comment: thanks for pointing me on that direction mike :) , i will have a look now :)

Comment: Mike is correct. Extensions cannot access VS Code's underlying DOM. PreviewHtml is you best bet for arbitrary html content but it only gives you control over the contents of a document view

Comment: thanks Matt and Mike. Yes i can see. Its a shame because it makes it again very close :( . I cannot even create a bottom panel on the side of the console then, that would have been a good alternative.

Comment: But you can open a preview window where you have full control over the html code and the DOM. You can include your own JS code and even do animations. Here's an example using D3.js for a graph display: http://www.soft-gems.net/files/atn.gif. I plan to use such a preview also for my own grammar debugger (the built-in stuff doesn't fit what I actually need).